# Inside Windows 2016 : error message : "Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty"

Tags: java, certificate, keytool, windows-server-2016, truststore

Inside Windows 2016 : error message:

> "Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty"

Can you explain the problem ?
How technically (commande or interface) fix the problem ?

I don't want to rebuild new certifcates (cacerts and clientstore.jks).
Because, the rest of the web application is working.
I just have a new script to clean something (purge) that don't work.
The software editor doesn't help me.

I don't know how to check my java certificates:

> keytool -list -cacerts
> Keystore type: PKCS12
> Keystore provider: SUN\
> Your keystore contains 1 entry
> toto-tutu.eu, 26 mars 2024, trustedCertEntry,
> Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx: